# Obtaining a function given by the user in Python

Tags: python, function, parsing, typeerror, sympy

I'm having a problem to read a function using the `parse_expr` sympy function.
Here's how I'm using it:

```
from sympy import*
import sympy as smp
import numpy as np
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
print("Welcome...")
x=smp.Symbol('x')
function=input("Enter your function in terms of X\nIf you want to use Fixed point method input de G(x) expresion\n")
function=parse_expr(function, x)
```

And here's what I'm getting:

```
Welcome...
Enter your function in terms of X
If you want to use Fixed point method input de G(x) expresion
2*x

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jp159\Desktop\Desktop\Studies\Exercises.py", line 8, in <module>
    function=parse_expr(function, x)
  File "C:\Users\jp159\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\parsing\sympy_parser.py", line 988, in parse_expr
    raise TypeError('expecting local_dict to be a dict')
TypeError: expecting local_dict to be a dict
```

Comment: go back and read docs for that function!

Comment: Well if that was the solution for me, someone new to coding, I would have solved it already, don't you think?

Comment: @JuanArango still, `x` looks nothing like a `local_dict` ([ref](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html))

Comment: Well, I thought they meant something different to a literal dictionary but thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't expect new programmers to fully understand the function documentation, but I like to see them make the effort.  In this case, "what did it mean by a `dict`?"

Comment: Ty man I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an isympy session initialized with:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
>>> k, m, n = symbols('k m n', integer=True)
>>> f, g, h = symbols('f g h', cls=Function)
>>> init_printing()

Documentation can be found at https://docs.sympy.org/1.8/
```

Since local_dict is optional, lets omit it:

```
In [1]: parse_expr('2*x')
Out[1]: 2⋅x
```

but we can make a dict - that references one of the defined symbols:

```
In [4]: parse_expr('2*x',{'x':x})
Out[4]: 2⋅x

In [5]: parse_expr('2*x',{'x':y})
Out[5]: 2⋅y
```

I can also use a string that doesn't look like any defined symbol:

```
In [7]: parse_expr('2*X')
Out[7]: 2⋅X

In [8]: _.free_symbols
Out[8]: {X}
```

One key skill for new programmers is reading the documentation.  Yes, often that can be hard to understand, but still it should be the first stop.  SO (and general web searches) should come later.

`sympy` is written in Python, so as basic knowledge of that language is assumed.